# Categories with subcategories: Case: When click on button it displays only last sub-category

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a news section on my webpage and i need to create categories with sub-categories.

I need category (for example Band) button to combine all values (tags(subcategories)) from rows to display only news in that category.

Like this:

- **Band** (when you click on Band it displays all news from Gigs Music Albums):
- Gigs (when you click it displays news only with tag): Gigs
- Music
- Albums

I already made a table in MySQL called news which includes row called **tags** and I have table **category** which includes row category (Band) and subcategory (Gigs Music Albums).

```
category | subcategory
Band     | Gigs
Band     | Music
Band     | Albums
```

Comment: De-igorised cathegorys.

Comment: What exactly is the question here - how to restrict your query to all articles containing any descendant category of anything in the tags?

Comment: You say you have a field in the `news` table called `tags` - you will probably need to break that out to a `news_tags` connecting table in order to pull that off.  CSV lists of tags won't help you much.

Comment: Orbling, if it helps, i'am using something like this to sort $news = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE tags LIKE "%'.$cath.'%" ORDER by id DESC LIMIT '.$howmany.'');

Comment: and this $cath is my cathegories that i need to display, it should look like this: %gigs%music%albums, but it takes only last value and looks like this %albums, i have while function to display all theese rows, and i have $_post function that posts info into $cath